# How to make responsive this menu code ? ( one expert )

Tags: css

My problem is this menu, which I can not make responsive for all resolutions. Maybe you know how to edit it better, I can't manage this menu in order to be responsive (position, size and text size). I want to make size and position responsive in percent or other solution. Thank you very much, I'm waiting for your help.
[Demo codepen](https://codepen.io/GARDFIELD3/pen/RKXoWY)

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

#cssmenu > ul {
     width:100%;
      BACKGROUND-COLOR: RED; 
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000%;
  -moz-perspective: 1000%;
  perspective: 1000%;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #c61515;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
 font-weight: bold; color: #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-23px);
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  color: #dff2fa;
  background: #19799f;
  content: attr(data-title);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(- -18px);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a::before,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover::before {
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center > ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li,
#cssmenu.small-screen.align-center {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #dff2fa;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen > ul > li > a::before {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #3db2e1;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  width: 22px;
  height: 3px;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
  border-top: 2px solid #dff2fa;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dff2fa;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 27px;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.small-screen #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
  background: #dff2fa;
}
```

Comment: It's better to use some media queries rather than depend completely on percentage sizing. For example `@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 580px) { }` use this query for dedicated style for screen sizes between 480px and 580px.

Comment: not work ;)  You make him work and have all my respect..

Comment: but this you can make responsive ? https://codepen.io/GARDFIELD3/pen/oZgOrX

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress, it is better to use some plugin for responsive menu, but if insist not to do that, you should use `@media` queries. Look at this: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpwRwr
I changed this codes:

```
<ul>
 <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'><span>FORUM</span></a></li>
 <li><a href='#'><span>SERVERE</span></a></li>
 <li><a href='#'><span>ASISTENTA</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

and added this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  #content ul li span {font-size: 11px}
  #cssmenu ul li {width:25% }
  #cssmenu ul li a {padding: 16px 10px 16px 10px}
}
```

This changes make it a little more responsive but the point is in using media queries, use it and build the layout you like. But in the case of WordPress, look at [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-menu/) too.

Comment: @AlexandruMihai I don't get it, you want it to be responsive so it has to have some changes in size and position.

Comment: mediaqueris is a solution ?

Comment: @AlexandruMihai I think so.